# How to display the form that is to be based on its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, combobox, jcombobox

I wish I could show the form that I selected in my combo (between student and employee)

The problem is probably my jquery because by changing the values that hides or displays the form but I want her displays the form desired by changing the value of my combo
student --> StudentForm
employee --> EmployeeForm

**But when I change the value of my list the form stays the same ...**

*here is my code with my forms*

> user_profile.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends "polls/base.html" %}
{% block title %}Création d'un profil{% endblock %}
{% block bodyId %}userProfilePage{% endblock %}
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> -->

{% block content %}
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayRightForm() {
    if ($("#profileType").val() == 'student') {
        $('#employeeForm').hide();
        $('#studentForm').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#studentForm').hide();
        $('#employeeForm').show();
    }
}
$(document).ready(displayRightForm);
$('#profileType').change(displayRightForm);
</script>
<h1>Création d'un compte</h1>

<form>
    <p>
        <label for="profileType">Vous êtes :</label>
        <select id="profileType">
            <option value="student" {% if studentForm.is_bound %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>Étudiant</option>
            <option value="employee" {% if employeeForm.is_bound %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>Employé</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</form>

<form action="register" method="GET" id="studentForm">
    {{ studentForm.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>
        <input type="hidden" name="profileType" value="student" />
        <input type="submit" value="Créer un compte" />
    </p>
</form>

<form action="register" method="GET" id="employeeForm">
    {{ employeeForm.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>
        <input type="hidden" name="profileType" value="employee" />
        <input type="submit" value="Créer un compte" />     
    </p>
</form>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css"/>
{% endblock %}
```

> The jquery works because if I pass

```
if ($("#profileType").val() == 'student') {
            $('#employeeForm').hide();
            $('#studentForm').show();
        }
```

> in

```
if ($("#profileType").val() == 'student') {
        $('#employeeForm').show();
        $('#studentForm').show();
    }
```

This shows me two good form to follow

I use this link for the jquery, It is correct?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks for your time guys !

Comment: Why `$(document).ready(displayRightForm);` called 2 times ?

Comment: this is a mistake sorry i have edit

Comment: Checkout my answer below.

Comment: yes jquery must be included before your script tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your script as below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        displayRightForm();
    });

    function displayRightForm() {
        if ($("#profileType").val() == 'student') {
            $('#employeeForm').hide();
            $('#studentForm').show();
        } else {
            $('#studentForm').hide();
            $('#employeeForm').show();
        }
    }

    $('select').on('change', function() {
        displayRightForm();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That does not change form again :/

Comment: Only the studentForm is displayed

Comment: i have try with your method but it does not work with me :3 I am desperate

Comment: someone else has another solution?